# Backbone.js route doesnt trigger page render

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, routes

When I click on a button, I catch the click in View with:

```
events:{
   'click .parameter-input a': 'saveParameter'
},
```

In saveParameter function i do this:

```
saveParameter: function(ev) {
        parameter.value = $('.parameter-input .param').val();
        console.log(parameter.value);
        router.navigate("#/page2/" + parameter.value, {trigger:true});
        return false;           
    }
```

And my routes are defined like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "home",
      "page2/*parameter": "UIpage2",
    }
});

var page1 = new Page1();
var page2 = new Page2();

var router = new Router;
router.on('route:home', function() {
    page1.render();
    console.log("page1 render");
})
router.on('route:UIpage2', function(parameter){
    page2.render();
    console.log("page2 render " + parameter.value);
})
```

Page2 is defined like this:

```
    var Page2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'.page',
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($('#page2').html(), {parameter: parameter});
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});
```

How can I force for .page to be refreshed again with page2 render when I navigate to it? Render on page2 never gets called..

Edit: parameter is a string value taken out of some input box and needs to be shown in URL like mydomain.com/#/page2/parameter and in some div on a page2.

Answer (score 1):

The hash should not be in the route, so replace

```
router.navigate("#/page2/" + parameter.value, {trigger:true});
```

by

```
router.navigate("page2/" + parameter.value, {trigger:true});
```

Also make sure you have initialized Backbone history with `Backbone.history.start()`.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "index",
    "bar": "bar",
    "page2/*parameter": "foo"
  },

  index: function() {
    console.log("on page index");
  },

  bar: function() {
    console.log("on page bar");
  },

  foo: function(data) {
    console.log("on page foo with data: " + data);
  }
});


var router = new Router();
console.log("router created");
Backbone.history.start();
console.log("initializing backbone history");
router.navigate("bar", {trigger: true});
router.navigate("page2/foobar", {trigger: true});
```

Comment: Tnx for answer. I did change that error but page still doesnt rerender.. Anything else you might need to see to find error?

Comment: Have you have called `Backbone.history.start()`?

Is `router.navigate` called properly? 
If it is, what is the value of `parameter.value`?

The callback for `route:UIPage2` is not called at all right?

Comment: I did call .start(), yes. Router.navigate is called: router.navigate("page2/" + parameter.value, {trigger:true}); is that OK? What do you mean by callback for route:UIPage2?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `www.xyz.com/#route1` in your URL and your again trying to execute `router.navigate('route1', {trigger: true});`, this won't trigger the route handler of `route1` because you are already on `route1`.

If you need to refresh the page i.e. re-render page2, just call `page2.render();`.

If you want to do it using router, you'll have to change the route temporarily and then route to your required page.(Note: This will add and unnecessary entry in your route history.) For e.g.: If you are already at `route1` i.e. `www.xyz.com/#route1` and you want to re-render view, do followig -

`router.navigate('temp', {trigger : false});`

Above line will change the URL in address bar but won't call any route handler. After that call

`router.navigate('route1', {trigger : true}); // this will now re-render view`